# Fetching data from Firestore and map it into a provider object

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I have a problem combining Firestore with the Provider (State Management) in Flutter. 
My problem is mainly to map the data retrieved from firestore on my class. -> Deserializing Firebase Data to a Dart Class

I am able to retrieve the data from Firestore and print it into the console.

If I want to use json.decode I always get "type xx ' is not a subtype of type 'Map'" which is also mentioned here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17417

My Run Class

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

enum Complexity { simple, challenging, hard }

class Run with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final List<String> workouts;
  final String imageUrl;
  final List<String> intervals;
  final List<String> steps;
  final int duration;
  Complexity complexity;
  final bool isRecovery;
  bool isBeginner;

  Run(
      {@required this.id,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.workouts,
      @required this.imageUrl,
      @required this.intervals,
      @required this.steps,
      this.duration,
      this.complexity,
      this.isRecovery,
      this.isBeginner});

  factory Run.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Run(
        id: doc.documentID,
        title: doc['title'] ?? '',
        workouts: doc['workouts'] ?? 0,
        imageUrl: doc['imageUrl'] ?? '',
        intervals: doc['intervals'] ?? 0,
        steps: doc['steps'] ?? 0);
  }
```

My Runs class which should fetch the data

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xxx/providers/run.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

final runsRef = Firestore.instance.collection('runs');

class Runs with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Run> _items = [];

  fetchRuns() async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
        await runsRef.getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        print(doc.data);
      });
    });
  }
```

1. I want to call the function fetchRuns to get all documents in the collection
2. I want to map this retrieved data to my Class
3. I want to use this class as a Provider to provide state/data to different screens

I am stuck at step 2 and can't really solve that.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I am using streams and this is how I am mapping the results.

```
  Stream<List<Run>> fetchRuns() {
    var snaps = Firestore.instance.collection('runs').snapshots();
    return snaps.map( (list) => {
          return list.documents.map((doc) => Run.fromDocument(doc)).toList()
       }
     );
  }
```

https://github.com/aaronksaunders/flutter_firebase_auth_app

See `lib/services/data.dart`

Comment: Hey Aaron, that looks very good and I will definitely try that out.

Only thing missing is I want to use the https://pub.dev/packages/provider to manage my state. I will still try your solution and getting the provider package wrapped up with it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ChristianJosephs - if you look at the project, it is using a provider i believe

Comment: thanks I guess I oversaw that.
Found a wonderful tutorial yesterday though check it out https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations-using-provider-c242a01f6a10